# Advertise a shortcut that is not nested in a File element

Tags: wix, wix3, shortcut-file

I am making an installer for an application that will create two shortcuts on the user's desktop if they check a box. Due to it being optional, I can't put the shortcuts under the file elements in question. I have to put them in separate components instead. Kind-of like this:

```
<!--Desktop shortcuts are optional-->
<Component Id="DesktopShortcut.Executable1" Guid="PUT-GUID-HERE" Directory="DesktopFolder">
    <Shortcut Id="desktopShortcut.Executable1" Advertise="yes"
        WorkingDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="Executable 1" Directory="DesktopFolder"
        Icon="icon.Executable1.exe"  IconIndex="0"
        Target="INSTALLFOLDER_._Executable1.exe"/>
    <Condition>
        AddDesktopShortcut=1
    </Condition>
</Component>
<Component Id="DesktopShortcut.Executable2" Guid="PUT-GUID-HERE" Directory="DesktopFolder">
    <Shortcut Id="desktopShortcut.Executable2" Advertise="yes"
        WorkingDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="Executable 2" Directory="DesktopFolder"
        Icon="icon.Executable2.exe" IconIndex="0"
        Target="INSTALLFOLDER_._Executable2.exe"/>
    <Condition>
        AddDesktopShortcut=1
    </Condition>
</Component>
```

But Wix doesn't like the target attribute. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

An advertised shortcut always points at the `KeyPath` of its Component. The KeyPath must be a file. Therefore, advertised shortcuts must live in the same Component that contains the file.

The WiX toolset is saving you from yourself by not allowing a `Target` attribute that could point at something not the KeyPath.

So remove Advertised=yes or Target attribute.